# How to create a for loop in Scala to compare 2 spark dataframes columns and their values

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have df1 and df2 and I need to compare their columns and if there are differences between them, to count them, so I can have a number miss match column added.

```
df1
+--------------------+--------+----------------+----------+
|                  ID|colA.   |colB.           |colC       |
+--------------------+--------+----------------+----------+
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              10|     APPLES|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              20|     APPLES|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              10|      PEARS|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              10|     APPLES|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              15|    CARROTS|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              10|      APPLE|
+--------------------+--------+----------------+----------+


df2
+--------------------+--------+----------------+----------+
|                  ID|colA.   |colB            |colC      |
+--------------------+--------+----------------+----------+
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              10|     APPLES|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              20|     APPLES|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              10|     APPLES|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              30|     APPLES|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              15|    CARROTS|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              15|      PEARS|
+--------------------+--------+----------------+----------+
```

I can only use the ID when comparing them and the rest need to be used dinamically.
What I did so far is to rename the column names and then join them:

```
   val columns: Array[String] = df1.columns
   val df1prefixed = df1.columns.map(c=>c + "_1")
   val df1_toDf = df1.toDF(df1prefixed:_*)

   val df2prefixed = df2.columns.map(c=>c + "_2")
   val df2_toDf = df2.toDF(df2prefixed:_*)

   val joined  = df1_toDf.join((df2_toDf), col("ID_1").eqNullSafe(col("ID_2")), 
   "full_outer")
   display(joined)
```

What I'm trying to do next is to compare colA_1 with colA_2 and if they are equal to print 0, otherwise 1 and same thing for all the columns and then add a new column named "Number miss match" where to add 0 or 1, depending on the comparison result.

I'm trying a for loop in Scala but I don't know how to do it:

```
for (column <- columns) { col(column + "_1") =!= col(column + "_2")), 1).otherwise(0)) }
```

Later update:
My final output should be like the following:

```
+--------------+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+
|Attribute Name|Total Records|Number Miss Match|% Miss Match|Status|
+--------------+-------------+-----------------+------------+---+
|          colA|            6|                0|       0.0 %|  Pass|
|          colB|            6|                2|      33.3 %|  Fail|
|          colC|            6|                2|      33.3 %|  Fail|
+--------------+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+
```

Comment: Spark is very focused on functional programming. Loops are not recommended. Use instead a ``when`` ``otherwise`` statement https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-case-when-otherwise-example/ if you want to compare things.

Comment: Any hints on how I can compare using when otherwise when I cannot use hardcoded column names?

Comment: @Anna if the two schemas are the same, why not just use `except()` to find the rows that are not present in one but are in the other. It also looks like you have an `ID` column identifier. So you can know which rows don't match exactly.

Comment: except is not enough for what I need for my final output. I've just edited my question and added how my final output needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advice to don't use loops for in spark, due the parallelism and functional approach you can have unexpected behaviours really hard to track. Instead I would suggest to use the `except` dataframe method which will compare dataframe 1 to dataframe 2 and create a new dataframe containing rows in df1 but not in the other df

Comment: Yes, but I need to compare all the column values and extract the differences. And I need to do this without using the column names.

Comment: @Marlon Menjivar an example of using `except` would benefit your Answer and hopefully explain to the OP how i can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the columns and create each time a single column dataframe for each of your source dataframes and use `except` to compare them. For example:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df1 = List((1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 6)).toDF("colA", "colB")
val df2 = List((1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 3)).toDF("colA", "colB")

df1.show()
//+----+----+
//|colA|colB|
//+----+----+
//|   1|   3|
//|   2|   4|
//|   3|   6|
//+----+----+

df2.show()
//+----+----+
//|colA|colB|
//+----+----+
//|   1|   2|
//|   2|   4|
//|   3|   3|
//+----+----+

val comparisonResultMap = df1.columns.map { case col =>
  val df1SingleCol = df1.select(col)
  val df2SingleCol = df2.select(col)
  val is_equal = if (df1SingleCol.except(df2SingleCol).isEmpty && df2SingleCol.except(df1SingleCol).isEmpty) 1 else 0
  (col, is_equal)
}.toMap

print(comparisonResultMap)
// output: Map(colA -> 1, colB -> 0)
```

Comment: Your Answer would benefit from supporting information which explains how this code solves the problem.